# class method process is not changing objects' attributes

Tags: python, class, python-multiprocessing

It's my second day in Python, I found it's a really cool language and I want to try different things in it.

Is it possible to call an object and create a daemon of that object's method which would change the objects attributes?

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time


class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 1
        # this attribute...

    def loop(self):
        while 1:
            print self.number
            # ...is changed here
            self.number += 1
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    f = Foo()
    p = Process(target=f.loop)
    p.deamon = True # this makes it work in the background

    p.start()

    # proceed with the main loop...
    while 1:
        time.sleep(1)
        print f.number * 10
```

The result:

```
1
10
2
10
3
10
4
10
...
```

Why doesn't `f.loop()` change the `self.number` of `f`? They are both part of the same class `Foo()`.

What can I change to receive this output:

```
1
10
2
20
3
30
4
40
...
```

**/edit 1:**

I tried this, with the same result (why?):

```
class Foo(Process):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Foo, self).__init__()
        self.daemon = True # is daemon
        self.number = 1
        self._target = self.loop # on start() it will run loop()

    def loop(self):
        while 1:
            print self.number
            self.number += 1
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    f = Foo() # is now Process

    f.start() # runs f.loop()
    while 1:
        time.sleep(1)
        print f.number * 10
```

Same output as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `multiprocessing`. The short (and somewhat simplified) answer is that processes to do not share memory by default. Try using [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) instead.

If you're hell bent on experimenting with shared memory and processes then look at [sharing state](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) in the documentation on multiprocessing.

Also `daemon` doesn't do what you think it does. If a process creates children then it will attempt to kill all it's daemonic children when it exits. All Processes will work in the background, you just need to start them.

Comment: Sharing state is not recommended :/ Also, I heard threading can ruin some data or something, if you're not careful. I didn't explore deeper.

Comment: I must've misread the documentation on `deamon`. My bad. I will try using `threading` instead. Thank you :)

Comment: The code you provide already shares state. If someone has tried to dissuade you, a learner, from using threading, then it is the same reason as avoiding shared state. Use `threading.Lock` to share state properly.

Comment: I will try to remember it when programming threaded apps. Thanks